# Sequelize : Add prefix in req.query

Tags: api, include, sequelize.js

(This is my first post, sorry if it's not perfect)

I am in the process of making an API in nodejs with "express", "body-parser" and Sequelize.

My HTTP API is working fine, however I am stuck on something.
Indeed, I have a "message" table linked to a "user" table

Association : message/user

```
db.user.hasMany(db.message, { foreignKey: { name: 'user_id', allowNull: false }, sourceKey: 'id', as: 'usermessage' });
db.message.belongsTo(db.user, { foreignKey: { name: 'user_id', allowNull: false }, targetKey: 'id', as: 'usermessage'});
```

Here is what I would like: Add a prefix to "req.query" when I call an include.

I have a "getMessages" route allowing me to get all the messages. I have included the "user" table

```
getMessages: function (req, res) {
        Message.findAll({
            include: [
                {
                    model: User,
                    attributes: ['id', 'email', 'username', 'language'],
                    as: 'usermessage',
                    where: (req.query) ? req.query : undefined,
                    required: true
                },
            ],
            attributes: { exclude: ['user_id'] },
            order: [
                ['created_at', (req.query.order) ? req.query.order : 'DESC']
            ],
            offset: (req.query.offset) ? parseInt(req.query.offset) : undefined,
            limit: (req.query.limit) ? parseInt(req.query.limit) : undefined,
        })
            .then((messages) => {
                return res.status(201).json(messages);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                return res.status(500).json({ 'error': 'Unable to find messages' });
            })
    },
```

When I want to fulfill a condition (example: find all the messages where the user's language is EN)
I make the following request: http://localhost:8080/message?language=EN
This query works!
However I want to put "usermessage.language=EN" instead of "language=EN", someone can help me please ?

Comment: If you add a `where` option to `include` you don't need to indicate an alias there along with fields used in a condition

Comment: If I decide to filter with the "id" (or another field who is in both model), like this : http://localhost:8080/message?id=1. It will create conflict ...

Comment: No, it won't because Sequelize automatically adds all necessary aliases for main model and for all included ones

Comment: if I put "where: (req.query) ? req.query : undefined" condition for my main model ("message model") AND the include model ("user" model). When I do the following request : http://localhost:8080/message?id=1, it will do the condition for both model, that is to say id=1 for "message" model and id=1 for "user" include model. And it's not what I want. I want to do the req.query depends on the include : http://localhost:8080/message?id=1 if I want the message with id=1 and http://localhost:8080/message?user.id=1 if I want all the messages where the id user = 1

Comment: So you want to add a condition always in main model's `where` option? Then if it contains a dot you need to wrap field name with $ like `$user.id$` and you also need to split field name and a value to properly construct a filter condition